# NameError with a has_many_through table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ties, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :albums, through: :ties
end

class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ties, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :ties
end

class Tie < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :album, dependent: :destroy
end
```

K... so, When trying to create an album, from the AlbumsController#Create action:

```
def create
  @album = current_user.albums.build(params[:album]) #error is on this line
  if @album.save
    flash[:success] = "#{@album.description} created!"
    redirect_to @album
  else
    flash[:error] = 'Looks like something was invalid with that album. Try again.'
    redirect_to albums_path
  end
end
```

I'm getting `uninitialized constant User::Ty`.  I think rails is confusing `Tie` with `Ty`.  Any idea?  Can I force certain names from `en.yml`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed because Rails is trying to singularize `ties` to derive the class name. The best way around this would be to define a new inflection rule for this. In Rails 4 you would do this:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.singular /^ties$/i, 'tie'
end
```

But in Rails 3 you would do this:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.singular /^ties$/i, 'tie'
end
```

Comment: Is there some reason you didn't suggest use of `irregular`, Ryan? Is that intended only for the case where the default rules don't work in either direction?

Comment: @PeterAlfvin: Yes, that's right. The singular for "ties" will be "tie" but if you pluralize "tie" you'll always get "ties".

Comment: `C:/railsinstaller/ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/inflector/inflections.rb:166:in 'inflections': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)` when trying to start the server after that.

Comment: Sorry, that was a Rails 4 application. Let me update it for Rails 3.

Comment: Good show.  one final fix, we have to capitalize Tie, since it's referring to the model.  Thanks, Ryan!